# Displaying query results from database, approaches, any ci helper?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, pagination

UPDATE:

How could/would i be able to display the results. My mind is blocked, i cant seem to think coz all my mind prioritizes is the design/look of how it would be displayed. If someone could show me in code how to display each of the data, i would be able to finish.

I have little to no time to make a better database structure so one table would suffice. :)

Table columns:
id
name
meal
cuisine
cooking
difficulty
description

Search View: 1st step

```
<h2>Results:</h2>

                <?php if($result == 0):?>
                No records found.
            <?php else:?>
                <?php foreach($result as $r):?>
                    <?=anchor('recipe_controller/show_recipe_search/'.$r->id,$r->name);?><br />
                <?php endforeach;?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <p>
                <?=$links?>
            </p>
```

Controller: 2nd step

```
public function show_recipe_search()
    {

    $to_show = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->db->where('id', $to_Show);
    $query = $this->db->get('recipe');
    $data['result'] = $query->result_array();

    $this->load->view('display_recipe',$data);

    }
```

View: 3rd step

```
<?php foreach($result as $r):?>
<h2><?php echo '$name'; ?></h2> // Recipe name
        <?=$r->echo rest of row;?><br />
                <?php endforeach;?>
```

Since my view is incomplete as my mind is rendering me paralyzed. IDK why. I just cant think of how i would be able to display the result. Should be easy but until i can picture the design i cant echo the results yet.

What does this error imply?

> a php error was encountered
>
> severity: notice
>
> message: trying to get property of non-object
>
> filename: views/display_recipe.php
>
> line number: 63

line 63 is `<h2><?php echo $r->name; ?></h2>`

Comment: why don't you want to use a uri_segment?

Comment: Coz it was a hassle the first time i started ci. I will be updating my post. Im currently using it. Would love to hear your opinion for better practice or implementation.

Comment: Well I'm trying to help you out but I can't figure it out what's your problem. what's wrong with doing this `anchor('showrecipe/'.$r->id)`

Comment: @FabioAntunes I am displaying the name using links. If i display the id it would make no sense since my search relies on recipe name. Also, how would the user know if the results returned are okay. I mean, if i were the user and i just saw bunch of numbers from 1-10. id be offly pissed. although, its still a good suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is generally thrown when an object cannot access a property, due to it being null. I'd imagine that the main idea is that you're not actually returning anything from the DB.

I suspect that your problem is on this line:

```
$this->db->where('id', $to_Show);
```

Can you try a var_dump() right after you execute your query or going through XDebug?

Comment: I just woke up. 

anyways, to make it clearer though, $to_show is $r->id i passed as a 3rd segment = controller/function/'.$r->id , $r->name

so far that passed the id then i declared $to_show in my controller and to retrieve that 3rd segment,

$this->uri->segment(3);

so far no php error on that, although. did i do it correctly?

Comment: I accepeted your answer, i tried var dump it returned null and an php error of undefined,

I removed result, it is now

$data = $query->result_array(); and it got the results i wanted,


idk why it wouldnt work if i add $data['result'] = this is equal to $result right? so why is this the problem

Comment: Hey, you can add parameters to a method, here's a link on how to do that: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri

I tend to avoid passing parameters using the "segment" option, since it's not really scalable and if you need additional parameters, you kind of lock yourself out. Also, what happens if your application needs to live in a sub-folder? (i.e. http://localhost/codeigniter/example) Everything will stop working. Use method parameters, the right way of passing data via GET.